# Open two views of the same PDF

Tags: macos, preview

Is there a way to open two views of the same PDF in Preview (without creating two copies of the file), or perhaps split the window and show two different pages at the same time?

This is very useful when reading a paper which refers back to equations on previous pages.

Comment: Did you find a nice GUI way of doing this over these years?

Comment: @becko Skim.app has split views, and will show a preview of link targets when hovering links. This way one can check what a reference is without having to click it. It's not perfect, but it's the best I found so far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Print dialogue choose the PDF button, Open PDF in Preview.

The temporary copy seems just to vanish when closed, as you would want; and it has the same name and location as the original. If you markup the new copy, it creates a duplicate with new name and you choose to save or not.

Answer (score 31):

Open the first one regularly and then use the `open` command with the `-n` option.

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `open -n` and drop the file into the Terminal window. The full path of the file will appear after what you've typed.
3. Hit enter.

The `-n` option opens a new instance of the application (in this case the default one, as no other is specified) even if one is already running.

Comment: Excellent!  Is there a GUI way to do this?  Would services be the way to set it up (if I use it often)? (New OS X user)

Comment: @Szabolcs It will be an approach, indeed.

Comment: In case someone doesn't know, you can select the file in Finder, press `Cmd+c`, open the Terminal, write `open -n ` and press `Cmd+v` to paste the path

Comment: If the PDF is edited in one of the windows, the other window jumps to the point of the edit. So friggin frustrating.

Comment: To add to @nachocab's comment, you can simply drag and drop the file in the Terminal.

Answer (score 7):

[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net) has menu items for marking a page and going back to a marked page. You can assign shortcuts to them in System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: It seems Skim has a split view too.  It's probably better to use Skim instead of preview.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: More directly in Skim, one can hold the Cmd key and click somewhere in your document.  A new "view"/window will open centered on where you clicked and both windows can now scroll independently.

Answer (score 1):

One other solution would be use your browser to open the PDF file.
For me is common to use chrome for reading a PDF when I want 2 instances of the file.
I also believe that is faster to search a word in a large PDF file using the browser than the PDF software.

Answer (score 1):

The "open -n" solution can be integrated to Finder using Automator.

For this, open Automator and select "Quick Action" for new document type. Then, select "Workflow receives current" "files or folders" in "Finder.app".

Then from the list of search items, enter "Run Applescript" and use the following script, which takes the selected file from finder and opens it using "open -n" command:

```
  on run {input, parameters}
    set pathToMe to POSIX path of input
    set command to "open -n " & "\"" & pathToMe & "\""
    # display dialog command #(this is for debugging)
    do shell script command

    return input
```

Save the document with name "Open with new instance". Then, when you right click on a pdf file on finder, the "Open with new instance" menu item will be available.

I have tried to bring this into the services menu of Preview, however I could not succeed in that. For now, finder integration works for me.

**Note:** When you use the File -> Print option suggested in the accepted answer, Preview temporarily creates a file with name: Filename.pdf.pdf. This means that, when you accidentally make highlights, annotations on the temporary file, you'll loose your edits when you close that temporary file. On the other hand, when you use the "open -n" solution, two instances of Preview works on the very same files. Edits to any of the files are reflected to other instance when you save it. The only glitch is, after editing in one instance of preview when you save the file, the other instances scroll to the same page. This actually happens after some timer expires, even if you don't save the file. If this is annoying for you, the File->Print approach would work better.

In the end, it is a plain shame that Apple does not implement a proper implementation of multiple views of same pdf document for Preview. Adobe Acrobat Reader does it very nicely, for example (Window -> New Window) however, for now, Adobe Reader has poor performance on Mac operating system, compared to Windows Operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of Copy and New from Clipboard lets you open any part of the PDF in a new window (with the caveat that it's not a view in the sense that modifications do not propagate to the original document). Use rectangular selection to select the part of the PDF you want in a separate window , e.g. a figure or chart, or select a whole page, and hit `command-c`-`command-n`.

Answer (score 0):

Opening new instance solution mentioned above may not be a good idea... because opening a new instance will open all the files you have opened with the original instance again (macOS 13.2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).